# scala: Remove columns where column value below median value for all columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In data reduction phase of analysis, I want to remove all columns where column total is below the median value of all column totals.
So with dataset:

```
v1,v2,v3
1  3  5
3  4  3
```

I sum columns

```
v1,v2,v3
4  7  8
```

The median is 7 so I drop v1

```
v2,v3
3  5
4  3
```

I thought I could do this with a streaming function on Row. But this does not seem possible.

The code I have come up with works, but it seems very verbose and looks a lot like Java code (which I take as a sign that I am doing it wrong).

Are there any more efficient ways of performing this operation?

```
  val val dfv2=DataFrameUtils.openFile(spark,"C:\\Users\\jake\\__workspace\\R\\datafiles\\ikodaDataManipulation\\VERB2.csv")

  //return a single row dataframe with sum of each column
  val dfv2summed:DataFrame=dfv2.groupBy().sum()

  logger.info(s"dfv2summed col count is ${dfv2summed.schema.fieldNames.length}")


  //get the rowValues
  val rowValues:Array[Long]=dfv2summed.head().getValuesMap(dfv2summed.schema.fieldNames).values.toArray

  //sort the rows
  scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(rowValues)

  //calculate medians (simplistically)
  val median:Long = rowValues(rowValues.length/2)

  //ArrayBuffer to hold column needs that need removing
  var columnArray: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer[String]()

  //get tuple key value pairs of columnName/value
  val entries: Map[String, Long]=dfv2summed.head().getValuesMap(dfv2summed.schema.fieldNames)
  entries.foreach
  {

    //find all columns where total value below median value
    kv =>

      if(kv._2.<(median))
        {
          columnArray+=kv._1
        }
  }

  //drop columns
  val dropColumns:Seq[String]=columnArray.map(s => s.substring(s.indexOf("sum(")+4,s.length-1)).toSeq
  logger.info(s"todrop ${dropColumns.size} : ${dropColumns}")
  val reducedDf=dfv2.drop(dropColumns: _*)
  logger.info(s"reducedDf col count  is ${reducedDf.schema.fieldNames.length}")
```

Comment: please share example data and expected output

Comment: done. Please see insertion above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calculating the sum of each column in `Spark`, we can get the median value in plain `Scala` and then select only the columns greater than or equal to this value by *column indices*.

Let's start with defining a function for calculating the median, it is a slight modification of [this example](http://fruzenshtein.com/scala-median-funciton/):

```
def median(seq: Seq[Long]): Long = {
  //In order if you are not sure that 'seq' is sorted
  val sortedSeq = seq.sortWith(_ < _)

  if (seq.size % 2 == 1) sortedSeq(sortedSeq.size / 2)
  else {
    val (up, down) = sortedSeq.splitAt(seq.size / 2)
    (up.last + down.head) / 2
  }
}
```

We first calculate the sums for all columns and convert it to `Seq[Long]`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
val sums = df.select(df.columns.map(c => sum(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
             .first.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Long]]
```

Then we calculate the `median`,

```
val med = median(sums)
```

And use it as a threshold to generate the column indices to keep:

```
val cols_keep = sums.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 >= med).map(_._2)
```

Finally, we map these indices inside a `select()` statement:

```
df.select(cols_keep map df.columns map col: _*).show()
+---+---+
| v2| v3|
+---+---+
|  3|  5|
|  4|  3|
+---+---+
```

Comment: very helpful. Thank you so much

Comment: NOTE: requires import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._